# In Shia's Islam, is it possible to make Nikkah again with that person from we recently take divorce?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, shiism

When a man had given divorce to his wife, recite all seegay ( that specific words by which divorce become properly valid ) and spent 3 months which gave the time for  thinking "Is the decision of divorce is good for them,they satisfied by their decision or not?", and after that he again want his wife back. Is it possible to make Nikkah again with that person or there is any specific Islamic rule or process to take wife back again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If he divorce once or twice it is possible to take the wife back with new nikah (marriage). If he divorced three times then he can not marry wife until wife marry with someone else and get divorced again. Please study Surat Baqarah 229 and 230 ayat.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible in Shiite Islam to be kind to the person we recently divorced?
Remarriage with the ex-spouse is not legally prohibited from divorce if the number of divorces is less than three. If the divorce is a reciprocal divorce, the couple can get back together before the end of 2 months and 4 days, without remarrying. If the divorce is of the Bain type of divorce, the man cannot take action to return his wife, and if he wants to return his wife, he must remarry her according to legal and sharia formalities.

Ref: https://jamejamonline.ir/fa/news/758319/%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%82-%D8%B1%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%B9-%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC-%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%AF%D8%AF-%DB%8C%D8%A7-%D8%AA%D9%86%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C